# Post-quantum X3DH

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography

I was trying to look into weather or not it would be possible to build a post-quantum version of the signal protocol. The [double ratchet algorithm](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) is trivial to modify, replacing the [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) key exchanges with [SIDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange) key exchanges appears to be enough (since you only have to publish  E, ϕ(P) and ϕ(Q) once) provided that there is a shared secret between all parties at the start. But the key exchange that signal uses to derive that shared secret, [X3DH](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/), is a problem. In the protocol there is a signed ECDH pre-key and the way the protocol specifies signing it is by using the identity key with [XEdDSA](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/) which is based on EdDSA (which can be broken by quantum computers) and the fact that Montgomery Eliptic curves are birationally equivalent to twisted Edwards curves. I can't figure out a way around this without wrecking some of the protocol properties. The most promising lead I could find is figuring out a way to do something similar with [RLWE-SIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_learning_with_errors_signature) and [RLWE-KEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_learning_with_errors_key_exchange) but I'm by no means an expert with lattice problems so anything I come up with would probably be bad and easily breakable. So is there a way to construct a post-quantum X3DH key exchange?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very much about X3DH specifically, but [Ben Smith's recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04803) is about isogeny-based cryptography and mentions X3DH on page 2. Unfortunately, that may be all it does, since I don't see any further discussion of X3DH. But it may be worth looking at.

As far as key signing goes, there is no good way to do isogeny-based signatures. If you only need one other party to validate the signature, you can use [designated verifier signatures](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6337933/), which do work well with isogenies. Otherwise you're probably stuck building your own thing, which as you mentioned is not something suitable for the non-expert.